# Cannot increment static variable within static class function

Tags: c++, class, object, static, arduino

```
class Stepper
{
  private:
    int enable;
    int direction;
    int speed;
    static int turretCounter;
  public:
    Stepper(int en, int dir)
    {
      enable = en;
      direction = dir;
      pinMode(enable,OUTPUT);
      pinMode(direction,OUTPUT);
      pinMode(4,OUTPUT);    
    }
    void Stop()
    {
      digitalWrite(enable,1);
      Timer1.detachInterrupt();
      Timer1.stop();
    }
    static void IncrementCounter()
    {
      turretCounter++;
    }
    //your step pin must be 4 due to limitations on static vars and methods
    static void Step()
    {
      digitalWrite(4,0);
      delayMicroseconds(1);
      digitalWrite(4,1);
      IncrementCounter();
    }
    void SetSpeed(int Speed)
    {
      speed = Speed;
    }
    void Run(int seconds)
    {
      digitalWrite(enable,0);
      Timer1.attachInterrupt(Step);
      Timer1.initialize(speed);
    }
    int GetCounter()
    {
      return turretCounter;
    }
    void SetDirection(int dir)
    {
      digitalWrite(direction,dir);
    }
    int GetSpeed()
    {
      return speed;
    }
};
```

I want to draw your attention to the static Step() method and static IncrementCounter() method. I've tried incrementing the variable within the Step() function but I always just get "error compiling for board Arudino Nano". I've tried to just call IncrementCounter() directly within the Step() method and I get the "cannot call class method without object" error. I get this error from Step() method.

Comment: *cannot call class method without object* should point to where in the code that error comes from.  What is that code?

Comment: Well that error comes from the Step() method. @NathanOliver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining `turretCounter` somewhere (preferably in a `.cpp`/`.cxx`/`.C` file) like this:

```
int Stepper::turretCounter = 0;
```

If this solves your problem, then probably you have overlooked a more informative error message and posted only the last line of your compiler output. In the future pay more attention to the compilation errors and make a habit to study them in the order they appear in the output (since later errors may be simply a result of earlier errors).